# Shared ownership for samba and Resilio Sync

Tags: permissions, samba

My external hard drive mounted at /media/backup_drive with ownership pi:pi. I have Resilio Sync running as user rslsync so it creates new files with rslsync:pi ownership. Now samba can't access these files that rslsync created. I tried using ACLs to add rwx rights to the rslsync and sambashare groups but Resilio Sync couldn't write like this. What would be the correct way to handle this situation other than setting everything to 777 rights?